# Error when compiling Apache CouchDB: use of opcode 153

Tags: erlang, debian, couchdb

I have some error when I compile Apache CouchDB on Debian 8.

Any idea what is wrong?

> =ERROR REPORT==== 30-Apr-2017::19:54:56 === beam/beam_load.c(1365): Error loading module compile:   use of opcode 153; this emulator
>   supports only up to 152
>
> =ERROR REPORT==== 30-Apr-2017::19:54:56 === Loading of /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/compiler-7.0.4/ebin/compile.beam failed:
>   badfile

Comment: Is "Error loading module compile: use of opcode 153; this emulator supports only up to 152" not ringing a bell?

Comment: Both those 'error reports' are erlang errors, so you might want to add an `erlang` tag to your question. 'compile' is an erlang module that should load automatically when erlang starts up. The second error seems to indicate that you are missing a required file. I would guess that both of those errors are due to an old/incompatible version of erlang.  Have you gone through: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/install/troubleshooting.html